# Replace example.org when generating url in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview

Step to reproduce:

- `rails new testurl`
- `cd testurl`
- Add `resources :tests, only: [:index]` in **config/routes.rb**
- Create a new file in **app/views/test/test.html.erb** with content of `<%= tests_url %>`.

What I need to do is render this view as HTML string, to do that I did the following:

- `rails c`
- Then run `ApplicationController.render(template: 'test/test')`

Running the code above gives me the following result:

```
irb(main):006:0> ApplicationController.render(template: 'test/test')
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering test/test.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered test/test.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 0.6ms | Allocations: 127)
Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 12.4ms | Allocations: 3390)
=> "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n  <head>\n    <title>Testurl</title>\n    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width,initial-scale=1\">\n    <meta name=\"csrf-param\" content=\"authenticity_token\" />\n<meta name=\"csrf-token\" content=\"Cl5oXyPFrAsZl_s3m_fO1ELVkFtUajlnI30AOZ0BB9LJpMbXnGjgX1Ng_JvQhcFo3VMD67a467Cs4mjcB_ODmA\" />\n    \n\n    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" media=\"all\" href=\"/assets/application.debug-ead91a25923de99455378da7f1f1bb5a6839a249af27af911ec2b81709b046b7.css\" data-turbolinks-track=\"reload\" />\n    <script src=\"/packs/js/application-f826770d917d8a37c1d8.js\" data-turbolinks-track=\"reload\"></script>\n  </head>\n\n  <body>\n    http://example.org/tests\n\n  </body>\n</html>\n"
```

As you can see `<%= tests_url %>` is rendered as `http://example.org/tests`. Where is this `http://example.org` defined? And how to replace it?

I tried searching `example.org` in a new rails app and found the following piece of code in **config/initializers/application_controller_renderer.rb**:

```rb
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# ActiveSupport::Reloader.to_prepare do
#   ApplicationController.renderer.defaults.merge!(
#    http_host: 'example.org',
#    https: false
#  )
# end
```

I tried uncommenting the code and replaced it with the following:

```rb
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

ActiveSupport::Reloader.to_prepare do
  ApplicationController.renderer.defaults.merge!(
    http_host: 'google.com',
    https: true
  )
end
```

Then after that, I restarted the app and rails console.

But still running `ApplicationController.render(template: 'test/test')` still gives me `http://example.org` where I expect it to be `https://google.com`. What seems to be the problem?

Environment:

- Ruby 2.7.2
- Rails 6.1.3

Comment: Did you try searching the Rails gem for this? https://github.com/rails/rails/search?q=example.org .  Or just opening it up with bundle and searching to see what change works?  Might take a while to find it, if it is even coming from the Rails gem, but then there is likely some way to override it I would think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found out how to change `example.org` globally but the solution below works enough for me.

```rb
renderer = ApplicationController.renderer.new(
  http_host: 'google.com',
  https: true
)

renderer.render(template: 'test/test')
```

Now it returns:

```
irb(main):016:0> renderer.render(template: 'test/test')
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering test/test.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered test/test.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 0.2ms | Allocations: 44)
Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 15.7ms | Allocations: 3133)
=> "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n  <head>\n    <title>Testurl</title>\n    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width,initial-scale=1\">\n    <meta name=\"csrf-param\" content=\"authenticity_token\" />\n<meta name=\"csrf-token\" content=\"M-u_LLixMIE-SgRpRiY0I-iqZiwvg2JAnJ14Oreqb8HCoQw5s7g00qPLMPg8kmmOImj1T-tekks_zMpMf0W_mQ\" />\n    \n\n    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" media=\"all\" href=\"/assets/application.debug-ead91a25923de99455378da7f1f1bb5a6839a249af27af911ec2b81709b046b7.css\" data-turbolinks-track=\"reload\" />\n    <script src=\"/packs/js/application-f826770d917d8a37c1d8.js\" data-turbolinks-track=\"reload\"></script>\n  </head>\n\n  <body>\n    https://google.com/tests\n\n  </body>\n</html>\n"
```

It now replaces `http://example.com` with `https://google.com`.